# Android - GridView onItemClick callback not being called When GridView is inside ViewPager

Tags: android, gridview

I have a ViewPager which holds a GridView.  This is the PagerAdaper's `instantiateItem` method:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emoticon_grid, null);
GridView grid = (GridView) page.findViewById(R.id.emoticon_grid);
grid.setAdapter(new EmoticonListAdapter(context, list, position));
container.addView(page);
grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        if(listener != null) {
            Emoticon selectedEmoticon = (Emoticon) arg0.getAdapter().getItem(arg2);
            listener.emoticonSelected(selectedEmoticon);
        }
    }
    });
    return page;
}
```

From what I can tell, Other people have encountered similar problems when adding inherently clickable views (e.g. Buttons) to GridViews.  But I am only using an ImageView

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Emoticon emoticon = emoticons[position];
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = new ImageView(context);
    }
    ((ImageView) convertView).setImageResource(emoticon.ResourceId);
    return convertView;
}
```

After adding debug logging and setting breakpoints in the onItemClickMethod, the callback is never getting called.

Answer (score 0):

if the goal is simply to get the notification, use `OnClickListener` instead of `OnItemClickListener`.  Set the listener via `setOnClickListener` in `getView` when `convertView` is null.  Otherwise, if you need the extra information that you would get in `onItemClick`, you can specialize `ImageView` to set and retrieve the convenience members that you define in the specialized class.